# Author and address relationship with EF Core

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys, relationship

I have a .NET application written with EF Core as ORM.

I don't know the relationship between an `Author` and `Address`.

- Is it possible to have addresses related to many authors?
- Is it a many-to-many / one-to-one / one-to-many relationship?

If for each author there is an address, in the case of an application with hundreds and hundreds of authors there would be many address entities duplicated right?

```
public class Author
{
    [Key]
    public int AuthorID { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public List<Book>? Books { get; set; }
    public Address? Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string? Street { get; set; }
    public string? City { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to have addresses related to many authors?

This is up to you to decide whether there are multiple authors living in the same house or not or, an author could have multiple houses. But you may build such type of relationship in EF Core.

> Is it a many-to-many / one-to-one / one-to-many relationship?

-If there can be an address related to many authors, it's an one-to-many relationship from address entity's POV. You will need to modify your Address class like this.

```
public class Address
{
    public string? Street { get; set; }
    public string? City { get; set; }
    public IList<Author>? Author { get; set; }
}
```

-If authors too going to have multiple addresses it will be a many-to-many relationship. In this case you will also need to modify your Author class.

```
public class Author
{
    [Key]
    public int AuthorID { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public List<Book>? Books { get; set; }
    public IList<Address>? Address { get; set; }
}
```